# What is the best approach for my class/subclass situation?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class which has four fields of which two will be assumed by "type".

Code below shows what i'm doing currently.

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public abstract class CodeHl7 {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String code;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String codeSystem;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String codeSystemName;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String displayName;

    public CodeHl7() {
    }

    public CodeHl7(String code, String codeSystem, String codeSystemName, String displayName) {
        this.code = code;
        this.codeSystem = codeSystem;
        this.codeSystemName = codeSystemName;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}

public class LoincCodeHl7 extends CodeHl7{
    public LoincCodeHl7(String code, String displayName) {
        super(code, "2.16.840.1.113883.6.1", "LOINC", displayName);
    }
}

public class TranslationCode extends CodeHl7{
    public TranslationCode(String code, String displayName) {
        super(code, "2.16.840.1.113883.3.4424.11.1.32", "KLAS_DOK_P1", displayName);
    }
}
```

And i simply dont even know if this is good approach or if it isn't what would be better approach? Some static methods that generate the codes with set parameters instead?